# Arduino Libraries documentation with all methods / functions

Tags: arduino

Is there in Arduino any page with all the functions availables as there is in Java, for instance  ?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html
I am checking the library Adafruit_NeoMatrix but I can't find all the functions available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that if it isn't an official arduino library it falls on the shoulders of the developer to write the documentation page for that library (for example the [Adafruit neo pixel](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/overview))

For more advance features and libraries try looking [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/)